# Unable to write dataframe into salesforce object. Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource

Tags: java, spring, pyspark, salesforce

I am trying to write the spark dataframe into salesforce object. But its failing with the below error.
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource (unrecognized type)**

I am able to read the data. But the write operation is failing. Not sure, I need to add any additional dependency or not.

**Dependencies used:**

```
spark-salesforce_2.12-1.1.4.jar
force-partner-api-40.0.0.jar
force-wsc-40.0.0.jar
jackson-dataformat-xml-2.4.4.jar
java-sizeof_2.11-0.1.jar
mockito-core-2.0.31-beta.jar
salesforce-wave-api-1.0.10.jar
scala-library-2.12.10.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.0.jar
stax2-api-4.2.1
```

**Pyspark Version : 3.3.0**

Below is my code.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("salesforce_connect").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc    = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("Error")

soql = "SELECT name, industry, type, billingaddress, sic, Phone, YearStarted FROM Account"
df = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce") \
                 .option("username", "dinesh123@force.com") \
                 .option("password", "password-securityToken") \
                 .option("soql", soql) \
                 .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                 .load()
df.show()

#Transformation
df = df.withColumn("YearStarted|", F.lit("2020"))\
        .na.replace("null", "Agriculture", "Industry")\
        .na.replace("null", "Default", "Type")
df.show()

df.write.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce") \
    .option("username", "dinesh123@force.com") \
    .option("password", "password-securityToken") \
    .option("sfObject", "Account") \
    .option("login", "https://sect-d3-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/")\
    .option("bulk", True)\
    .option("upsert", True)\
    .save()
```

**Below is the Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource (unrecognized type)
at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:802) at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:358) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:580)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:28) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1122) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3690) 
at com.springml.salesforce.wave.impl.BulkAPIImpl.addBatch(BulkAPIImpl.java:76) 
at com.springml.spark.salesforce.SFObjectWriter.$anonfun$writeData$3(SFObjectWriter.scala:45) 
at com.springml.spark.salesforce.SFObjectWriter.$anonfun$writeData$3$adapted(SFObjectWriter.scala:39) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2(RDD.scala:907) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2$adapted(RDD.scala:907) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329) 
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) 
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136) 
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548) 
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504) 
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, any update on this? I am facing the same issue. Please let me know if you have resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: No. Not yet. I tried with different versions of jars. But still no luck. We may need to increase or decrease the spark version I guess. Let me know if you get any workaround.

Comment: Hey, we decided to use the SalesForce Bulk API